# Insert a list of objects in microsoft word from c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word

i have a word template with bookmarks, and i want to insert informations of many persons in this word document,

So I have a Person class:

```
public class Person {
  string name;
  int age;
}
```

In an other class I have :

```
List<Person> personList;          // 5 person objects for example

object fileName = "C:\\Users\\akenna\\template.docx";
object readOnly = false;
object isVisible = true;
object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

// create instance of Word
Application oWordApp = new Application();

// create instance of Word Document
Document oWordDoc = new Document();

// open word document
oWordDoc = oWordApp.Documents.Open(ref fileName, ref missing, ref readOnly, ref readOnly,ref missing, ref missing, ref readOnly, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
```

Here I want to do an iteration to display all persons with personList[i] instead of personList[0] which shows only the first record

```
if (oWordDoc.Bookmarks.Exists("name"))
        {
            Object name = "name";
            Range range = oWordDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref name).Range;
            range.Text = personList[0].name;
            object newRange = range;
            oWordDoc.Bookmarks.Add("name", ref newRange);
        }
if (oWordDoc.Bookmarks.Exists("age"))
        {
            Object name = "age";
            Range range = oWordDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref name).Range;
            range.Text = personList[0].ToString();
            object newRange = range;
            oWordDoc.Bookmarks.Add("age", ref newRange);
        }
```

Expected result in word document:

```
Jack 20 
Mark 25
Isabelle 15
Mike 22
...... dynamic size
```

Comment: Whats the problem / error you are having?

Comment: No but i don't know how to iterate to show the informations in word document because personList has a dynamic size

Comment: Do you just have the 1 bookmark for the names and 1 for the age?

Comment: Yes I have two bookmarks :[name] : [age]

Comment: maybe i should have a third one like a global person bookmark and iterate on it, so can you help me to do this algorithm ?

Comment: Just looks a bit odd. If you loop through the persons list, the bookmark value will only ever be equal to the last entry with the code you have. It would be easier to have 1 bookmark called "nameandage". We can then build up a list of names and ages and set to bookmark value equal to that?

Comment: i'd suggest dumping the word application and going straight to the Open XML SDK https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK

Comment: Hello. I've added an answer based upon 1 bookmark. I just had concerns that if you tried to append data to 2 separate boomarks which are side by side, then the 2 items of data, name and age may have not lined up neatly. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed, based upon further conversations, the below demonstrates how to loop through a list of People, open the template, replace the bookmarks with content from the Person class and save the template as a new file.

Assuming a "Person" class similar to the below

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }

    public List<string> Experience { get; set; }
    public List<string> Skills { get; set; }
}


        object fileName = "C:\\Users\\akenna\\template.docx";
        object readOnly = false;
        object isVisible = true;
        object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        List<Person> personList = new List<Person>(); //Populate your list here

        foreach (Person p in personList)
        {
            // create instance of Word
            var applicationWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            var wordDoc = applicationWord.Documents.Open(fileName);

            //Supress word becoming visible
            wordDoc.Application.Visible = false;
            wordDoc.Application.WindowState = WdWindowState.wdWindowStateMinimize;
            wordDoc.Activate();

            //Loop through template bookmarks
            foreach (Bookmark bm in wordDoc.Bookmarks)
            {
                switch (bm.Name)
                {
                    case "Name":
                        bm.Range.Text = p.Name;
                        break;

                    case "Address":
                        bm.Range.Text = p.Address;
                        break;

                    case "Email":
                        bm.Range.Text = p.Email;
                        break;

                    case "Phone":
                        bm.Range.Text = p.PhoneNumber;
                        break;

                    case "Experiences":
                        var experienceText = "";
                        foreach (var exp in p.Experience)
                        {
                            experienceText = experienceText + exp + Environment.NewLine;
                        }

                        bm.Range.Text = experienceText;
                        break;

                    case "Skills":
                        var skillsText = "";
                        foreach (var skill in p.Skills)
                        {
                            skillsText = skillsText + skill + Environment.NewLine;
                        }

                        bm.Range.Text = skillsText;
                        break;
                }
            }

            var pathToSave = "C:\\Your Path To Save\\";
            var newFileName = p.Name + "_Resume.docx";

            wordDoc.SaveAs(pathToSave + newFileName);
            wordDoc.Close(WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges); //Supresses any messages from word.

            //You must do this to release the COM objects from memory!
            applicationWord.Quit();
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(applicationWord);
        }
```

Hope that helps now.

Comment: It will only works for a simple example whick it shows two words in one line,

Comment: I wanna add more fields like address, phone email ... and show them in a formatted style in the word document because the idea here is to fill a resume template

Comment: I've edited my answer so the string builder adds a newline manually. But yes you can achieve that with this approach. Build up your block of text for each section, i.e. address, phone and email.. and simply replace the bookmark with the string.

Comment: I understand but I want to add those informations in a specific position in a template which is already styled with bookmarks, any issues ?

Comment: No.. not that I can see. Although, if you are going to populate a resume template from a list of people, I guess you dont want to build up a list of names and ages? Surely you need to loop through the persons list and for each person, open the template, build up each bookmarks value, e..g. name, age, address, phone, set the bookmarks and then save the document as a new file for each person?

Comment: Well, I choose Person object just to explain, in fact i have a resume template, which has name, email, telephone... and professionnal experiences, education, achievements, which are a list of objects : List<Experience>   List<Achievement>     List<Education>

Comment: the problem is: the template has a static style and the lists have dynamic size, I can send you the word template if you want

Comment: Ok. the dynamic size of the lists doesn't matter. I'm editing my answer which should help.

Comment: thank you, but I only have one person and one template, i don't need to loop over persons, only the experiences and the skills which are lists

Comment: OK.. just remove the loop then and set a reference to the Person object and use that ref instead of "p"

Comment: It works but i forget to tell you that I have sub-bookmarks for each section, it means that for Experience section : we have [start year] - [end year] and [entreprise] and [mission], so we have to insert data over those bookmarks and not with a simple new line

Comment: @AmineKenna You need to put all relevant information *in* your question and think the question through before asking to make sure it's complete. It's unfair for you to keep changing the parameters when someone provides you with information that answers your original question.